# Passing latitude and longitude to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I went through loads of threads on the topic but I was not able to find the solution to my issue.

I am trying to write an app that would display list of GPS coordinates that are stored in SQLlite DB Once the user clicks on one of the entries they should be brought to another activity where the maps is displayed.

My list activity looks like that:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.coordinates_activity);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.item_layout,
            null,
            new String[] {LocationsDB.FIELD_ROW_ID, LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG},
            new int[] {R.id.row_id, R.id.row_lat, R.id.row_lgt }, 0);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


   mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){
  Intent intentlist = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fromlist.class);
  startActivity(intentlist);
    }
});
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Uri uri = LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
}


public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);
}
 public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


}
```

I have updated the onItemClick to:

```
  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

    TextView tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.row_lat);
    String lon_map=tv1.getText().toString();
    Double lon1 = Double.parseDouble(lon_map);

    TextView tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.row_lgt);
    String lgt_map=tv2.getText().toString();
    Double lgt2 = Double.parseDouble(lgt_map);

        Intent intentlist = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fromlist.class);
        intentlist.putExtra("lon1", lon1);
        intentlist.putExtra("lgt2", lgt2);

       startActivity(intentlist);
    }
```

The second activity looks like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fromlist_activity);


    double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lon1", 0);


    double longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lgt2", 0);
```

I still cannot get the values in the second activity

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: you need to use intents

Comment: How do I put the value stored R.id.row_lat and R.id.row_lgt to another activity.

Comment: I tried this:
TextView tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.row_lgt);
     String lgt_map=tv2.getText().toString();
     int lgt2 = Integer.parseInt(lgt_map);
     
      Intent intentlist = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fromlist.class);
      intentlist.putExtra("lon1", lon1);
      intentlist.putExtra("lgt2", lgt2);
but it is complete mess when it goes to another activityas ther is a double for the latitude and longitude

Comment: Bundle extras = new Bundle(); -> extras.putDouble(YOUR_LNG_KEY, tv2.getText().toString()); -> intentlist.putExtras(extras); ... What kind of "mess" are you getting on the other side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second activity try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fromlist_activity);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    double latitude = extras.getDoubleExtra("lon1", 0);
    double longitude = extras.getDoubleExtra("lgt2", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

put your data as extra to your intent

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){
  Intent intentlist = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fromlist.class);
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putDouble("lat", latitude);//latitude 
  b.putDouble("long", longitude);//longitude
  intentlist.putExtra(b);

  startActivity(intentlist);
    }
});
```

and in your `formlist` activity :

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(bundle b) {

   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
   latitude = b.getDouble("lat");
   longitude = b.getDouble("long");
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

(assuming you have a string you want to pass to the second activity).

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
    }
```

Read more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).